# How to make a button display random images on the slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I have here a simple program that displays random images that are in order, with two buttons that enable you to switch from an ascending order and then descending order. Now, I want to implement a random button that will display a random image of the selection but, I can't seem to figure out how. Below is my code:

```js
var images = [
  "1.jpg",
  "2.jpg",
  "3.jpg",
  "4.jpg",
  "5.jpg",
  "6.jpg",
  "7.jpg",
  "8.jpg"
];

var num = 0;

function next() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
  num++;
  if (num >= 8) {
    num = 0;
  }
  slider.src = images[num];
}


function prev() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
  num--;
  if (num < 0) {
    num = 7;
  }
  slider.src = images[num];
}

function random() {
  //where the code is supposed to be
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Laboratory Exercise 7</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button onClick="prev()"> &lt;--- </button>
    <img id="slider" SRC="1.jpg" width="200px" height="100px" />
    <button onClick="next()"> ---&gt; </button>
    <button onClick="random()"> Random </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [random number js min max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126901/random-number-js-min-max). Just get a random index and show image with this index

Answer (score 0):

There are your problem decission:

```
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Number(min + Math.random() * (max - min)));
}

function random() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("slider");  
  slider.src = images[random(0, 7)];
}
```

The first function is returning random number from 0 to 7 (all your images in arrays) and after that the second function set random number like index and take a image from the array with that index.

But you also can minimaze your code like that, just take out slider variable outside every function.

`var slider = document.getElementById("slider")`;

I hope that it will help to you!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the assist and, quick question; can I input either of those functions?

Comment: @StellarisGhost what do you meen? are you about: can you use this in your script or what?

Comment: sorry, I misread the details you provided. Sorry hehe

Comment: @StellarisGhost that`s okay, did it help to you?

Comment: not quite. It isn't functioning like how I want it

Comment: @StellarisGhost how do you want?

Comment: would it be possible for you to try the code yourself? Just so you can see for yourself. Do take note that you need placeholder images. @Danil Safonov